Derivative with respect to a derivative -- is covariant or contravariant?
I use the common physics notation "$,\nu$" to mean $\partial/\partial x^\nu$. Since
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu'}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\nu'}}$$
we recognize $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}$ as a covariant vector, according to its transformation law. What about $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\nu}}$? Is this a covariant or contravariant vector?
In my particular situation, I've got a Lagrangian $\mathscr{L}=\mathscr{L}\left(g_{\alpha\beta}(x), g_{\alpha\beta,\nu}(x)\right)$, and I am working with the expression
$$\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial g_{\alpha\beta,\nu}}.$$
Now (in my particular case) $\mathscr{L}$ is not a scalar, so forget about $\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial g_{\alpha\beta,\nu}}$ being any kind of vector. I am just trying to ascertain whether the $\nu$ should be written upstairs or downstairs.

To study $X^{\mu\nu}:=\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x_{\nu}}$ in terms of which we can write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\nu}}=X^{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}$, use$$\delta_{\rho}^{\nu}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\nu}}(g_{\mu\rho}x^{\mu})=X^{\nu\sigma}g_{\mu\rho,,\sigma}x^{\mu}+g_{\mu\rho}X^{\mu\nu}.$$

The simplest way to figure this out is to look at how it changes under a change of basis (it suffices to consider constant vectors and covectors). In fact, just checking what happens under rescaling by a scalar factor is enough to tell you the answer. It's an extremely useful thing to do during a calculation, because it will catch 99% of your errors.
